# Angular routing doesn't work for controllers with same module names

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

This is a simple angular app which seems to have a silly mistake in the code, I'm not quite able to figure it out.
The problem lies with the routing. Clicking on the links doesn't take me to the specified template url, instead reloads the same index.html page.

However, the link in the address bar changes to:

http://localhost:8000/app/#/stats

http://localhost:8000/app/#/sports

on clicking the respective links.

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My AngularJS App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>

  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers/myStats.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers/mySports.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <a ng-href="#/stats">My Stats</a>
    <a ng-href="#/sports">My Sports</a>
  </div>
  <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider
      .when('/stats', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/stats.html'


      })
      .when('/sports', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/sports.html'
      })
}]);
```

I hope there's nothing wrong with my directory structure:

[image: Directory structure for the application]

**EDIT:**

sharing code for controllers, the problem is in the controllers. It has to do something with angular modules having same names, although this was how I was taught.

**js/controllers/mySports.js**

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
    .controller('mySports',['$scope', function($scope){
        console.log('just checking');

    }]);
```

**What worked:**
Changing module name in mySports.js from **myApp** to **mySports**, and then injecting **mySports** as a dependency in **app.js**.

Updated **app.js** to this:

```
'use strict';
    angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute','mySports'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
      $routeProvider
          .when('/stats', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/stats.html'
          })
          .when('/sports', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/sports.html'
            controller: mySports,
          })
    }]);
```

**EDIT**

What still remains the question is to why change the module names of controllers and then inject as dependencies into **app.js**? Why not have the same module names?

Comment: May be this `ng-href="#/` to this `ng-href="/#` ?

Comment: @litestone - This reloads the page to index of http://localhost/

Comment: @ddepablo - this takes me to a page that simply says "Not found". On looking in Networks tab in Dev tools, it gives a 404

Comment: This is working fine on my machine. Don't know what's the issue. Try running `http-server` from the root directory and see the log for issues

Comment: Are you sure `ng-app="myApp"` can be defined on the `<html>`. I have almost the same code except for `ng-app` directive declared on `<body>`.

Comment: @Toxantron - I had thought of that, didn't make any changes in the behaviour.

Comment: found a solution, but doesn't explain why the original one doesn't work. See update to question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works: http://codepen.io/C14L/pen/oxqEZE

Problem is, that you are re-defing your main module, when you're defining your "mySports" controller here:

```
angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('mySports',[...
```

There is a ',[]' and that overwrites the `ngRoute` previously injected. Do instead

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('mySports',[...
```

*without* the `,[]` part, then it should work.

That is also the reason why injecting mySports into myApp works, because myApp's injections array doesn't get overwritten in that case.

Comment: Perfect explanation, this works. Removing the '[]' totally makes sense, as it was overwriting the main dependency array.

Answer (score 5):

You need to inject ngRoute as dependency to the application

Change

**From:**

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
```

**To:**

```
angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute'])
```

Here is the working [`Application`](http://plnkr.co/edit/HaV938MlD5JwDGGIxypd?p=preview)

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. ngRoute was there before, I removed it for experimentation. Edited the question now, it still doesn't work. There seems to be something else wrong

Comment: That is it! The `app` in your URL. I recall angular having problems with non-root index pages.

Comment: @Toxantron - I don't understand. Do you want me to remove app directory somehow, and launch the application from "http://localhost:8000" instead of "http://localhost:8000/app" ?

Comment: @Sajeetharan - yours work. I changed the code the way you have, removed the directory structure to have everything in the same directory level, and included controllers in the main app.js file instead of having them separately. It did not make any changes at all. I think there's something wrong with the dependencies, or may be something else but not routing

Comment: @kamal0808 create a plunker for your issue

Comment: @Sajeetharan - doing it now.

Comment: @Sajeetharan - check this please http://plnkr.co/edit/Vl4miUIkfWB6YH0uPiUy?p=preview

Comment: @Sajeetharan - i see what you did, removed the <base> tag which i realized had I had put as one of the users here suggested. This works perfectly in plunker, not sure why doesn't work in my localhost. This is strange. I may be missing something basic here

Comment: if you can give team viewer, i can check

Comment: @Sajeetharan - updated question, found solution, but still need clarification on that

Answer (score 0):

Check the [angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#relative-links) for relative links. The `app` you have in your URL needs to be declared as base like this:

```
<head>
  <base href="/app/">
</head>
```

Comment: I gave this a try. Doesn't make any changes. Moreover, on clicking the links, the address bar does change the urls and include '/app' after 'http://localhost:8000'. I think it's smart enough to check for itself that the project lies in app directory

Comment: But isn't this where it supposed to be? As far as I understand your application is hosted at http://localhost:8080/app/

Comment: yes, my application is hosted at "localhost:8000/app".

Answer (score 0):

In your script of the HTML, try to add the min.js file instead of the .js only, thats a example:

```
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

You should have a min.js in that folder, **AND! very important**, dont add first the route files, this may be a good add:

```
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/myStats.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/mySports.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: that seems to be a really bad idea, it will say angular not found in app.js

Comment: true my fail, check it now, but the important is the min.js

Comment: I don't see how minified files may change the app behaviour. However, I found a solution, see the question update. But the solution still doesn't answer the original question, see if you can help

Answer (score 0):

I see it perfectly OK. 
I have working example here https://plnkr.co/edit/Thm6Xw66BUmjxeGydFFJ?p=preview
Just couple of checks you can consider

1. The file permission. It should be (755)
2. The path. Take the files outside the `partials` folder and try

Good luck

Comment: The file permissions are 755.
Taking outside partials folder doesn't make sense to me, there are meant to be partial views. I want them in partials folder. Do you want me to change the path specified somewhere?

Comment: The console has no errors. Please check question update

Answer (score 0):

For the updated question, to use the same module everywhere you could define your module as follows :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
 $routeProvider
  .when('/stats', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/stats.html'
  })
  .when('/sports', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/sports.html'
  })
}]);
```

and your controllers as:

```
app.controller('mySports',['$scope', function($scope){
    console.log('just checking');

}]);
```

Comment: Hey this works. But how do the controllers access the variable "app" without defining them first in their own js files? Secondly, I had studied that declaring modules in variables and then reusing variables is a bad practice. Why not define the modules everytime when a controller is to be defined?

Comment: Its just that the variable in which you store the main angular module, `app` in the code above, gets stored globally and  you can access this any where. Try console.log(app) and check in firebug.

Comment: Understood. Thus, any variable declared in js files is a global variable I assume. Anyway, it works without variables too. Check the best answer that I chose